# pythonTypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am multiplying two list where I get error when try to multiply both lists. When I pass the y_pred then here I got the error of multiplication as shown in code.What I do to solve this problem?

```
def polynomial_features(data, deg):
    data_copy=data.copy()
    #print(data_copy.head())
    for i in range(1,deg):
        data_copy['X'+str(i+1)]=data_copy['X'+str(i)]*data_copy['X1']
    return data_copy

x_pred = pd.Series({'X1':[i/200.0 for i in range(200)]})
y_pred = model.predict(polynomial_features(x_pred,deg))
```

I got the error in the list line of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your input to the function must be a `dataframe`, not a series -

Change this:

```
x_pred = pd.Series({'X1':[i/200.0 for i in range(200)]})
```

To this:

```
x_pred = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[i/200.0 for i in range(200)]})
```